# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Validator' not found

Tags: laravel, api, validation, postman

I tried to make a validator for API in laravel
But this error appears

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Validator' not found

How can I solve this?

Comment: And where is your validator class? Show us some relevant. Ofe not only the error. Otherwise is hard to guess it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the facade at the top of your class

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

You can also call the Facade alias like so

```php
\Validator::make.....
```

Anywhere in your code if you have the alias set in `config/app.php` (it is by default)

```php
'aliases' => [
    // Other aliases omitted for brevity
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class, // <--- Here
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
],
```

Hope this helps

Comment: "Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::false does not exist." This error appeared when I tried to put use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Comment: That's not how validation works, please edit the question and show your validation code

Answer (score 0):

Just use your controller

```
use Validator;
```